# why read(1) function call two times in readable event in node js?

Tags: node.js, readable

There are one file 'foo.txt' where 'koushik' is written.
code:-

```
   var fs = require('fs');
   var rr = fs.createReadStream('foo.txt');
   rr.on('readable', function() {
     console.log('readable:', rr.read(1));
   });
   rr.on('end', function() {
     console.log('end');
   });
```

output:-

```
k
o
```

Comment: Because the `readable` event is triggered twice. Some more context would be useful here, what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

The [`readable` event](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_readable) is emitted when there is data available to be read from the stream.

The [`read(1)`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_read_size) you have in that event handler will read one byte from the currently available data, each time the `readable` event fires.

It triggers twice because the file handling in node.js decides to fire it twice.

You may get the output you expect if you instead use no argument to `read()`

```
var fs = require('fs');
var rr = fs.createReadStream('foo.txt');
rr.on('readable', function() {
  console.log('readable:', rr.read()); // read all available data
});
rr.on('end', function() {
  console.log('end');
});
```